# Пустой ответ на mysql-запрос через php

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!
Подсобите победить неведомую и кажется простяцкую фигню)

```
        $select_group=$mysqli->send_query("
  SELECT
      channel.channel_id,
      channel.group,
      output.channel_id,
      output.interface,
      output.port,
      output.path
  FROM
      output,channel
  WHERE
      channel.group='РАДИО' AND
      channel.channel_id=output.channel_id
  ");
    while($row = $mysqli->assoc($select_group)){
        echo $row['path'];
    }
```

Если этот запрос делать в Mysql, то он нормально отрабатывает и возращает список. А через php пусто)

Comment: проблема в функции send_query()

Answer (score 0):

```
$cn = dbConnect();
    $q = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT
      channel.channel_id,
      channel.group,
      output.channel_id,
      output.interface,
      output.port,
      output.path
  FROM
      output,channel
  WHERE
      channel.group='РАДИО' AND
      channel.channel_id=output.channel_id
  ");
    $List = Array();
    while($out=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        $List[] = $out;
    }
    return $List;
```

Вот пример, он тут вернёт из базы в массив

Answer (score 0):

Все функции работы с базой я вынес в отдельный подключаемый класс.
Вот выдержка из него :

```
    // Отправка запроса в базу данных
    public function send_query($sql) {
        return $this->_db->query($sql);
    }

    // Перевод в ассоциативный массив
    public function assoc($data) {
        return $data->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

начнем с того, что `send_query`

> Эта функция УСТАРЕЛА и была УДАЛЕНА начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0.

Удалена в 5.3.0, 8 лет назад Карл!

Используйте [query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

Продолжим вопросом, откуда вы вообще взяли функцию `assoc`? Такой в документации нет, зато есть [fetch_asscoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)